# Documentation for GLVideoItem for GStreamer 1.16.1

Tags: qt, qml, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm integrating a (pure) RTP stream into a Qt 5.15.2 Application using GStreamer 1.16.1. Within QML there is "import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.GLVideoItem 1.0" and "GstGLVideoItem" as suggested by the GStreamer play-sample https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/blob/1.16.1/tests/examples/qt/qmlsink/main.qml

Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation or further help about the "GstGLVideoItem" or potential other QML items for GStreamer.

Does anybody know where to find e.g. all properties of "GstGLVideoItem"?

Namely, I wonder if there is information about the video stream, such as FPS or width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source there aren't much properties for `GstGLVideoItem`.

```
qmlRegisterType<QtGLVideoItem> ("org.freedesktop.gstreamer.GLVideoItem", 1, 0, "GstGLVideoItem");
```

The source for `GstGLVideoItem` can be found  [here](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/blob/20bbeb5e37666c53c254c7b08470ad8a00d97630/ext/qt/qtitem.h). The header shows that it is derived from `QQuickItem`, so it has all the QML `Item` properties plus the two listed in the header (depending on the version you are using).

```
Q_PROPERTY(bool itemInitialized
            READ itemInitialized
            NOTIFY itemInitializedChanged)
Q_PROPERTY(bool forceAspectRatio
            READ getForceAspectRatio
            WRITE setForceAspectRatio
            NOTIFY forceAspectRatioChanged)
```

There is also the function `setDAR(gint, gint)` which is publicly available.

Comment: thank you, this answers my question. Would have hoped for more..